# include file within a switch case statement

Tags: php

Is it possible in an include file to have incomplete statements.
e.g. in my case i want to repeat this code ->

```
case "c":
case "d":
case "e":
```

i place this in an include file, file.inc.php

```
<?php
case "c":
case "d":
case "e":
```

and the normal run code is this:

```
switch {

 case "a":
 case "b":
  //something gets done here!
  break;

 include ('file.inc.php');
  //do something here - doesn't work tho
  break;

}
```

can this be done? From what i can see i'm not even sure the include file is included? the switch just looks for a and b only, no errors.

Comment: My own opinion is that the code with `include ('file.inc.php');` isn't clear, you may have to go though a few includes to understand what the switch statement is doing.

Comment: no, but you can have another switch in the include.

Comment: Thanks all... looks like it can't be done then.. i just want to avoid having to write whats in the include file numerous times as i have various switches where case d,e,f are repeated . thanks again for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can this importation of cases into a switch block be achieved?

#### Yes.

Should you implement it?

## NO!

As so many before me have fervently stressed, `eval()` is "evil" and it is giant flashing symptom that there is something very awkward/inappropriate about your project structure.  In the end, you should take the time to re-factor your project so that this technique is no longer necessary.

Now, to prove that it is possible... A workaround is to replace the `include()` call with a `file_get_contents` call to fetch the include file's contents and insert the string as a piece of a complete `switch()` block using `eval()`.

Tested Codes:

**broken_switch.php**

```
<?php
$includedCases = file_get_contents('evaled.inc.php');
foreach (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] as $letter) {
    echo "<div> $letter => ";

    eval('
        switch ($letter) {
            case "a":
            case "b":
                echo "switch value satisfied by a or b as normal";
                break;          
            ?>' . $includedCases . '
                echo "switch value satisfied by c, d, or e from eval\'ed include file";
                break;
            default:
                echo "default case";        
        }
    ');
    echo "</div>";
}
```

**evaled.inc.php**

```
<?php
case "c":
case "d":
case "e":
```

Output from **broken_switch.php**:

```
a => switch value satisfied by a or b as normal
b => switch value satisfied by a or b as normal
c => switch value satisfied by c, d, or e from eval'ed include file
d => switch value satisfied by c, d, or e from eval'ed include file
e => switch value satisfied by c, d, or e from eval'ed include file
f => default case
```

This is just a demonstration.  I am not going to bother "optimizing it" because the point I am making is that this technique **SHOULD NOT BE IMPLEMENTED**.

Comment: appreciate the input. yeah i certainly wouldn't go down this road as you state, it should not be implemented :)! as a self-taught, winging-it programmer i suppose i find it odd that a 'straight' include file without complete statement cannot be done

Comment: If you could amend your answer at the top and put that it can't be done but this is a workaround then i can mark this is the answer My question really was can include files contain incomplete statements and looks like this is not possible. hope you not offended! i think i'd get slammed if i accepted this as is.

Comment: No one is going to slam you for accepting a clear, correct answer that advises you (and others) NOT to use `eval()` even if it does legitimately enable the desired behavior.  I cannot edit my post to say that it is impossible, after I have proven that it is indeed possible.

Comment: i disagree with what you say .. you use file_get_contents and in your code there is no include statement. it is a workaround. just add a footnote to your answer unless a moderator agrees with you.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I actually forgot what function I used.

Answer (score -1):

Please read php manual for switch case. i think your code not working with  this syntax.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

```
switch {

 case "a":
 case "b":
   //something gets done here!
   break;
 case "c":
   include ('file.inc.php');
   //do something here - doesn't work tho
   break;
}
```

Comment: So is this the really long way of saying "I don't think so" then copy-pasting half of the OP's question?  Doesn't look very well supported, even if it is true.

Comment: @mickmackusa i just wrote correct syntax which i think, he might forgot to write last case

Comment: Case `c` is "unknown" to the parent file, this is not a valid substitute for the provided scenario.

Comment: Ok @mickmackusa thanks for guide me,i wrote whatever i learned

Comment: @PriyankMotivaras appreciate your input. as people have stated case "c": would be in the include file

Comment: @Priyank do you know why my correct/tested answer is downvoted?

Comment: I can understand the downvote on your answer, as my answer disproves your assertion.  If the no-comment downvote on my answer is not from you, then I will assume that it from the person(s) who have been repeatedly doing the same on many of my recent, correct answers.

Comment: @mickmackusa wasn't me,i haven't downvoted any comments or answers.